# IBM Cloud Private: How to alert on keywords in logs

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

Does ICP provide alerting on logs or this is something extra? My use case is to alert on critical exception keywords in application logs. ICP's Prometheus alerts deals with metrics/numbers. I am familiar with Graylog which uses ElasticSearch and it provides alerting feature. What is the ICP recommendation for alerting on messages/events in logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with elastalert: https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert
https://github.com/bitsensor/yelp-elastalert

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer so I can collect my SO karma :)

Comment: Hi @David Karlsen - Why can we not use OOB Elastic Rules and Connectors to create an alert for this? There seems to be a special kind of rule (log threshold rule) especially for this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/current/logs-threshold-alert.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ICP supported or inbuilt log alerting then there isn't any. You may have to rely on external tools build upon elastic search as David as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: Please refer to my comment on David's answer.